# Проверка запущенной службы и обработка ошибки

Tags: c#

Каким образом можно отловить запущена ли другая программа и в случае ее работы, запускается моя. Если нет, то выпадает ошибка.
У меня сейчас вот такой код

```
public Form1()
    {
       string pName = "steam.exe";
       Process[] pList = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process myProcess in pList)
        {
            if (myProcess.ProcessName == pName)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
             else{
                MessageBox.Show("Steam не запущен!!!!");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }

    }
```

При старте программы выпадает ошибка. Отрабатывает ветка else. Хотя сам Steam у меня запущен.

Comment: У вас на первом же процессе с другим именем случается завершение программы.

Comment: @Monk А как мне выйти из данной ситуации?

Comment: Оставьте только ветку if, а ветку else уберите.

Comment: @Monk заработало. Но теперь если тот же Steam не запущен, то у меня просто появляется пустая форма.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Первый способ: вводим булеву переменную-флаг.

```
string pName = "steam.exe";
Process[] pList = Process.GetProcesses();

bool found = false;

foreach (var myProcess in pList)
{
    if (myProcess.ProcessName == pName)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!found)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Steam не запущен!");
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

#### Второй способ: делаем дополнительный метод.

Рекомендуемый способ.

```
bool FindProcess()
{
    string pName = "steam.exe";
    Process[] pList = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach (var myProcess in pList)
    {
        if (myProcess.ProcessName == pName)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Используем его:

```
if (FindProcess())
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Steam не запущен!");
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

#### Третий способ: используем `goto`

("Ай, больно! Только не по голове! Не надо ногами...")

Нерекомендуемый способ.

```
string pName = "steam.exe";
Process[] pList = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (var myProcess in pList)
{
    if (myProcess.ProcessName == pName)
    {
        goto FOUND;
    }
}

MessageBox.Show("Steam не запущен!");
Environment.Exit(0);

FOUND:
InitializeComponent();
```

---

Вообще, лучше вынести этот код из конструктора формы в файл Program.cs, в метод `Main`. Если нужное приложение запущено, только тогда вызываете строку `Application.Run(new Form1());` - открывается ваша форма. В противном случае нет смысла даже вызывать форму.

Comment: Ого. спасибо за развернутый ответ:)

Answer (score 0):

```
        private static void SimplifySign(ref int numerator, ref int denominator)
        {
            if (numerator < 0 && denominator < 0)      // (-)/(-) -> (+)/(+)
                goto changing_sign;

            if (numerator > 0 && denominator < 0)      // (+)/(-) -> (-)/(+)
                goto changing_sign;

            return;                                    // (+)/(+) or (-)/(+) or (0)/(-) or (-)/(0)

        changing_sign:
            numerator = -numerator;
            denominator = -denominator;
        }
```

Попробуйте сделать этот код через if else или через методы.

1. Более громоздко
2. Лишние методы, которые непонятно как назвать и которые замедляют код

А я считаю, что goto можно и нужно использовать.
П.С. Много раз видел, как это делают разрабы в библиотеках С#

Простите за оффтоп, это был ответ тем кто брыжжет слюной на goto

Comment: Я в своём ответе уже описал способ с goto. / Ваше сообщение формально не является ответом на заданный вопрос.

Comment: это не ответ, это призыв к тому, чтобы подумать над словами "не используйте goto"

Comment: Если вы хотите обсудить достоинства и недостатки `goto`, то следует создать новую тему. Опубликуйте свой код и добавьте метку `инспекция кода`. Тут goto элементарно заменяется локальной функцией. А ещё можно паттерн-матчинг применить - выйдет даже короче.

Comment: Лично я обеими руками за возможность использования низкоуровневых конструкций, за то, чтобы язык предоставлял полный доступ к железу. Меня очень разочаровывает, когда из СУБД Sql Server убирают расширенные хранимки на C/C++, когда в C# запрещают Thread.Abort и тому подобное. Наличие goto позволяет в C# реализовать Duff's device. И я рад его наличию. Однако, в большинстве случаев можно прекрасно обойтись без него.

Comment: Читал книгу "Чистая архитектура" Робина Мартина. В главе, посвещенной структурному программированию сказано о вреде оператора goto. Скорее всего все поэтому и агрятся на него. Но там также сказано,

"Кроме того, даже языки, сохранившие
ключевое слово goto, часто ограничивают возможность переходов
границами текущей функции." 

То есть goto в C# не опасен, как и в других языках. Его ограничили. Может в нем кроется еще что-то - не знаю. Но суть в том, что иногда с его помощью можно сделать код более выразительнее. И дело не в Duff's device

Comment: Задайте отдельный вопрос на эту тему. Там вам подробно распишут о достоинствах и недостатках goto (угу, напихают полную панамку). Ваш код я по крайней мере двумя способами перепишу без goto, причём выйдет даже короче.

Comment: Та читал я этих тем... Последнее слово: в документации C# нет ни слова о проблемах оптимизации методов с goto. 
И это при том, что на каждом углу все кричат о том, что C# скорость не нужна, потому что доступ к базам данных намного медленнее. И тут же за забором надпись: на C# пишут приложения для десктопа

Comment: Бу! https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1458944/184217

Comment: `goto` за вас компилятор сделает, городить метки там где не надо - зло. Это код в 3 строки можно переписать безо всяких переходов с одним `if`. Если вы придумаете хоть один код, который с переходами будет понятнее и лаконичнее смотреться чем с любыми другими конструкциями языка, я тут же посыплю голову пеплом и попрошу начальство перевести меня в джуны. Я не противник `goto`, я просто не вижу в нем никакого смысла.