# Как выйти из цикла for, если условие было сделано ранее чем закончился оператор for

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void checkUser(char *userlogin, char *userpassword);
void enterFild(char *userlogin, char *userpassword);

int main() {
char userlgn[30];
char userpwd[30];

checkUser(userlgn, userpwd);

return 0;
}

void enterFild(char *userlogin, char *userpassword) {
cout << "Enter the login: ";
cin >> userlogin;

cout << "Enter the password: ";
cin >> userpassword;
}

void checkUser(char *userlogin, char *userpassword) {
const char    loginAdministrator[] = "Admin";
const char passwordAdministrator[] = "Admin";

enterFild(userlogin, userpassword);

int cmplogin = strcmp(userlogin, loginAdministrator);
int cmppassword = strcmp(userpassword, passwordAdministrator);

if (cmplogin == 0 && cmppassword == 0) {
    cout << "\nYou have been entered as administrator." << endl;
}
else {
    for (int verify = 0; verify < 3; verify++) {
        cout << "\nUncorrect login or password.\n\tAttempts to enter left " << 3 - verify << endl;

        enterFild(userlogin, userpassword);
        if (cmplogin == 0 && cmppassword == 0) {
            cout << "\nYou have been entered as administrator." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\nAccess denied!The number of attempts is limited!" << endl;
}
```

}

Comment: что не так с командой `break`?

Comment: @Igor видимо то, что всё равно выведется "превышено число попыток", но это уже ошибка логики, а не цикла for

Comment: Есть три известных способа: дополнительная переменная-флаг (или одна из уже существующих переменных) + `break`, введение дополнительного метода + `return`, использование `goto`. Можете посмотреть [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/657472/184217) на C#.

Answer (score 2):

Обновляйте значения `cmplogin` и `cmppassword` внутри цикла:

```
enterFild(userlogin, userpassword);
cmplogin = strcmp(userlogin, loginAdministrator);
cmppassword = strcmp(userpassword, passwordAdministrator);
```

И проверяйте их значения прежде чем выводить "Access denied!".

Answer (score 0):

Если бегло править ваш код - я бы сделал так:

```
#include <iostream>

int checkUser(std::string& sUserLogin, std::string& sUserPassword);
void enterField(std::string& sUserLogin, std::string& sUserPassword);

int main()
{
    std::string sUserLogin;
    std::string sUserPassword;

    return checkUser(sUserLogin, sUserPassword);
}


void enterField(std::string& sUserLogin, std::string& sUserPassword)
{
    std::cout << "Enter the login: ";
    std::cin >> sUserLogin;

    std::cout << "Enter the password: ";
    std::cin >> sUserPassword;
}


int checkUser(std::string& sUserLogin, std::string& sUserPassword)
{
    static const std::string sAdminLogin("Admin");
    static const std::string sAdminPassword("Admin");

    for (auto i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        enterField(sUserLogin, sUserPassword);
        if (sUserLogin == sAdminLogin && sUserPassword == sAdminPassword)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```