# Goto vs Рекурсия

Tags: c#

У меня есть метод, в это методе я сначала использовал рекурсию, но решил перейти на циклы или goto, перешёл на goto(да да, я знаю, что это плохо:) ), так как ключевое слово continue было уже занято вложенным циклом.

Я хотел бы узнать может из-за goto переполнится стек как из-за рекурсии? Или после перехода с помощью goto стек освобождается от памяти которая занята в метке?

Comment: `goto` не использует стек. Открою небольшой секрет: "под капотом" все циклы состоят из `if + goto`. `continue` и `break` - это тоже `goto` `goto` не любят, так как оно может прыгнуть в любую точку текущей функции. А это тяжело отслеживать и легко запутаться в этих переходах.

Comment: `while (true) { ... }` вместо `goto` вполне рабочее решение. И с ним проще работать. Есть один язык, где я применяю аналог `goto` регулярно, и назвается он там `jmp`. И его там любят и используют все. :) А в C# оно не нужно, как минимум потому что 90% циклов легко заменяются Linq запросами. Как по мне, рекурсия полезна только там, где есть деревья, лучший способ пробежаться по дереву. Ну это про императивные языки, есть еще функциональные, и рекурсия там - основополагающая фича языка, там все по-другому.

Comment: @aepot, jmp в asm это конечно хорошо:), но а если цикл не получается использовать continue уже используется во вложенном? Можно флагами, но красивее и удобнее ли это, чем goto?

Comment: @AimonZ. Да посмотреть бы пример кода, может там и не надо никакого goto

Comment: @AimonZ. если "в лоб", то `bool` переменная + `break`, и при выходе из вложенного цикла, если `true`, то `continue`.

Comment: еще вариант: разбить на функции + `return`

Comment: Да можно придумать, как зарефакторить почти всё, но без конкретного кода никак нельзя )

Comment: Кстати. Что значит "так как ключевое слово `continue` было уже занято вложенным циклом" - во вложенном цикле своё `continue`, а во внешнем своё. Непонятно опять же без кода, в чём прикол.

Comment: Я смотрю, в комментах бурная дискуссия. Поучаствую. Предлагаю посмотреть на [goto](https://www.google.com/search?q=maki+goto&client=firefox-b-d&hl=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwju_oaGgaPrAhXDFXcKHetNCOoQ_AUoAXoECBsQAw&biw=1760&bih=989), проблему решать с помощью АОП/метапрограммирования/макросов, автора забанить во избежание...

Comment: goto вполне логично использовать в небольших методах. Иногда оно даже прибавляет ясности коду, уменьшает дублирование кода в if/else а также уменьшает количество вызовов методов (тут не могу сказать точно, потому что возможно компилятор эти вызовы функций как-то оптимизирует.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сперва ответ на вопрос: нет, стек не может переполниться из-за использования `goto`.

В частности, потому, что в C# переход невозможен на метку вне области (scope) видимости.

Подробности в спецификации: [The goto statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-goto-statement).

---

Теперь пофилософствуем. Какие есть способы решения проблемы - выход из нескольких вложенных циклов? Собственно, они уже были перечислены автором и комментаторами:

1. Переход на метку с помощью `goto`
2. Использование дополнительного булева флага
3. Применение дополнительного метода, куда выносится вложенный цикл

Примеры [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/657472/184217).

---

В некоторых языках программирования есть дополнительные способы выхода из циклов. Например, в Java можно писать `continue label`.

В других языках можно вводить собственные синтаксические конструкции благодаря макросам. Например, в Nemerle. В нём легко сделать конструкцию как в Java и многое другое. Постепенно из этого языка перетягиваются в C# разные вкусности. Остаётся лишь надеяться, что когда-нибудь и гигиенические макросы возьмут на вооружение.