# Возможна ли жизнь без goto?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, goto

@Artem [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1454866/184217) опубликовал следующее сообщение:

```
static void SimplifySign(ref int numerator, ref int denominator)
{
    if (numerator < 0 && denominator < 0)      // (-)/(-) -> (+)/(+)
        goto changing_sign;

    if (numerator > 0 && denominator < 0)      // (+)/(-) -> (-)/(+)
        goto changing_sign;

    return;                                    // (+)/(+) or (-)/(+) or (0)/(-) or (-)/(0)

    changing_sign:
    numerator = -numerator;
    denominator = -denominator;
}
```

> Попробуйте сделать этот код через if else или через методы.
>
> 1. Более громоздко
> 2. Лишние методы, которые непонятно как назвать и которые замедляют код
>
> А я считаю, что goto можно и нужно использовать.
> П.С. Много раз видел, как это делают разрабы в библиотеках С#.

Несмотря на все мои просьбы, оформить это отдельным вопросом он отказался.
Что ж, сам сделаю это, т. к. хочу показать лёгкие способы обойтись без `goto`.

Comment: Главное не начинать думать, что если goto нет на верхнем уровне, то он вообще не нужен. На нижнем уровне он используется везде: и в командах ветвлений, и в циклах, и в переключателях. Безусловные переходы есть везде, просто они скрыты. Как открытие и закрытие файла в "File.ReadAllText".

Comment: @rotabor - есть архитектуры процессоров, у которых нет явной команды goto (или jump). Обходятся командами сравнения и перехода. Так что и на самом нижнем уровне железа возможна жизнь без goto.

Comment: это от экономии. Команда условного перехода со специально установленным истинным условием становится командной безусловного перехода.

Answer (score 6):

Так нормально?

```
static void SimplifySign(ref int numerator, ref int denominator) {
    if (numerator != 0 && denominator < 0) {
        numerator = -numerator;
        denominator = -denominator;
    }
}
```

Comment: Нормально. Хотя вопрос скорее о том, бывает ли код, в котором не обойтись без goto.

Comment: Такого кода не бывает - любой код записывается без goto. Иногда goto удобен, чаще только мешает.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не бывает. :) если даже вы придумаете ужасный код с `if-else`, то придет `switch-case` и всё исправит.

Comment: @aepot, как правило goto удобен при работе с вложенными циклами

Comment: @Grundy если больше 2 уровней воженности, то явно что-то пошло не так, на методы же бить код можно (и нужно). Но да, такие переходы без разбивки по методам могут оказаться удобными.

Comment: @aepot, а также вспомните, что эффективная реализация FSM делается на массиве меток

Comment: Этот пример лучший, кроме того факта, что условие становится не совсем понятное.
Может и у меня оно без комментариев не особо понятное, но с разгону у меня условие поделено на конкретные блоки, изолированные друг от друга логически, что для могза человека более понятно именно в данной ситуации ( может я и не прав)

Comment: Хотя беру слова назад. Ваше условие лучше акцентирует внимание на denominator, по сути все проблемы из-за него (знак должен стоять в числителе, если только там не ноль)

Comment: @Artem а если в числителе ноль - то о каком знаке вообще речь? Проверка числителя тут вовсе лишняя.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, если в числителе ноль, в знаменателе желательно держать единицу. Ноль - особый случай. Вы правы в том смысле, что если убрать условие на числитель, то хуже стать не должно. Но это за рамками вопроса. По условиям задачи функциональность задана, требуется выразить её наиболее "правильным" способом.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, объясняю почему так. Потому что обычно под дробь создают ридонли структуру. И обычно эта дробь упрощается после каждой операции. Тут показан пример упрощения знака. Зачем он нужен? Потому что у структур очень важно реализовать метод Equals , если я буду забивать на знаменатель, когда в числителе ноль - у меня одна и та же дробь (по значению) будут отличаться.

Comment: @Artem вы только что объяснили почему вам **не** следует оставлять отрицательный знаменатель при нулевом числителе.

Comment: Да, но в вашем примере вы не будете проверять вообще есть ли он там или нет.  Но у меня просто еще мысля была о том, чтоб хранить знак, потому что 0/число  = бесконечно малое, а не ноль

Comment: Не заморачивайтесь над кодом. Это кусок с учебного задания, который просто я сделал через goto

Comment: Вы ж не забывайте, что вызов любого метода - это аж два(!) безусловных перехода: один туда, другой обратно. То есть их как бы и нет, но в то же время они как бы есть.

Answer (score 2):

> Лишние методы, которые непонятно как назвать

А у вас, @Artem, лишний блок кода и метка, которую тоже непонятно как назвать.
Есть название метки: `changing_sign` - так же называем метод:

```
static void SimplifySign(ref int numerator, ref int denominator)
{
    if (numerator < 0 && denominator < 0)
        changing_sign(ref numerator, ref denominator);

    if (numerator > 0 && denominator < 0)
        changing_sign(ref numerator, ref denominator);

    void changing_sign(ref int numerator, ref int denominator)
    {
        numerator = -numerator;
        denominator = -denominator;
    }
}
```

Длиннее? Нет, практически так же.
Добавилась пара фигурных скобок, убавилась строка с `return`.

Метод сделан локальным, так что нигде снаружи не виден и не мешается.
Метод я всё же назвал бы `ChangeSign`.

Вообще, современные языки позволяют писать очень лаконичный код не прибегая к низкоуровневым конструкциям наподобие `goto`. Тут можно упомянуть и кортежи (value tuple) вкупе с деконструкцией, и паттерн-матчинг.

```
static (int, int) SimplifySign(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    if (numerator < 0 && denominator < 0)
        return (-numerator, -denominator);

    if (numerator > 0 && denominator < 0)
        return (-numerator, -denominator);

    return (numerator, denominator);
}
```

Как тебе такое, Илон Маск?
Использование:

```
(x, y) = SimplifySign(x, y);
```

---

> которые замедляют код

Современные компиляторы делают очень много оптимизаций.
Короткие методы могут быть заинлайнены. Циклы развёрнуты. Переменные убраны.
И вот как раз использование `goto` может сильно нарушить эти оптимизации. Потому что в компиляторах нет оптимизаций, умеющих обрабатывать `goto`.
Можно попенять разработчикам компиляторов, что они такие-сякие, не предусмотрели это. Да, вполне можно улучшить оптимизаторы в расчёте на это. Но сложность компиляторов и так чрезвычайна, поэтому нагружать их действиями, которые будут выполняться крайне редко, нет смысла.

Comment: Если речь уж зашла про современный язык, то тогда уж [так](https://dotnetfiddle.net/woXyPc), без всяких `if`.

Comment: Ага, а вот и `switch` подъехал ) @EvgeniyZ вы ток в примере перепутали один знак, а так можно было бы `or` добавить, ибо 2 выхода одинаковых.

Comment: Как писал Д. Кнут, структурность программы определяется ее структурой, а вовсе не отсутствием операторов goto...

Comment: Опять же, можно даже создать еще 10 конструкций сверху и сделать перегрузки всех этих 10 конструкций, но рано или поздно вы окажетесь на самом первом этаже, где нужно минимальными способами реализовать задачу. Если вы будете пытаться просто экономить буковки на мониторе - вы получить элементарную операцию, которая тянет вагон и тележку ненужных инструкций. Вы тут создали целую дженерик структуру (если он еще не использовался или нет прототипа в библиотеке) затем вы создали несколько копий структур данных

Comment: @Artem и снова рассуждаете исходя из незнания, как компилируется код. Просто поверьте на слово, вы не в курсе какой IL выдаст сборщик и какой ассемблер выдаст JIT для конкретой конструкции. Я пока не увидел ни одного примера, который бы демонстрировал уникальные возможности оператора перехода так, что без него получилось бы только хуже, хоть по читабельности, хоть по производительности. Одни слова.

Comment: Ваши слова про конечный автомат? или я уже поплыл? это не пример? Еще раз говорю - сам майкрософт его использует. Значит его можно использовать - просто там где он нужен или где вам удобнее. Если вы так скурпулезно подходите к вопросу рефакторинга кода - в чем проблема создать такой же продуманный понятный код с использованием goto?

Comment: @aepot Если уж говорить про IL, то там без goto уж никак не обходится. Любой цикл, любой if использует два перехода: один условный, один безусловный. Скорее всего, на верхнем уровне можно обойтись без goto.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, или вот так, используя ["защитную проверку](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science))", инвертируем условия и досрочно выходим, если нужные условия не выполняются, а дальше идёт остальной код:

```
static void SimplifySign(ref int numerator, ref int denominator)
{
    if (numerator == 0 || denominator >= 0)
        return;

    numerator = -numerator;
    denominator = -denominator;
}
```

Преимущества такого подхода:

- Понятно, как идёт поток управления, нет прыжков в нескольких местах кода
- Основной код точно так же идёт без отступа, как и при `goto`

Понятно, что пример был очень искусственный, но в общем случае обычно можно код зарефакторить до небольших функциональных кусков и с помощью нескольких ходовых приёмов сделать так, чтобы и логику кода было легко понять, и никакие сложные переходы не были нужны при этом.

Comment: однако дубляж) но я лайк поставил

Comment: @Artem Да я вроде специально смотрел - похожий код есть, но всё-таки не такой. Наиболее похожий кусок есть в удалённом ответе aepot, но он удалён и всё-равно не полностью такой же )  Ну либо я слепой, что тоже может быть )

Comment: @Artem Ещё в лучшем ответе, конечно, код тоже похожий, но всё же там не использован приём защитной проверки )

Comment: я про него и говорю. У вас просто инверсия этого варианта

Comment: @Artem Да, но то, что у меня - это прям отдельный приём, имеющий собственное название https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересно! Только я не понял сути. Читабельность возрастает за счет отсева? То есть в конце мы видим чистую логику?

Comment: @Artem, меньше вложенность фигурных скобок. Полезно если много условий.

Answer (score -2):

Хорошо. Суть моего "Фє" было в том, что все всячески обсерают тех, кто использует goto. Я не собираюсь спорить по этому поводу, просто хочу сказать пару вещей:

1. Мой пример наверное не самый удачный, я его выбрал, потому что недавно его сделал сам и мне он показался нормальным.
2. Уменьшение количества строк в коде - не всегда ведет к пониманию сути. Лучше написать на 1-2 строчки больше и наглядно видеть как работает код.
3. Goto хейтился за то, что многие языки позволяли его использовать "тупо" в любой точке программы и прыгать в любую точку программы  - что действительно запутывает и действительно становится сложно оптимизировать код. Когда goto используется внутри метода, где компилятор не занимается никакой магией типа итераторов, замыканий, асинхронностью и подобными штуками - думаю проблем с оптимизацией нет.
4. Я программист без опыта работы, всегда занимался этим как хобби. Сейчас хочу войти в профессию в C#. Раньше я изучал С++ и с каждого "утюга" слышал такую фразу, что вызов метода = большие затраты.

Во первых это обращение к старшим инструкциям, потом копирование/передача локальных параметров, создание и расширение стека.

Возможно в С# это никто не учитывает, возможно и в С++ оптимизация это решает, но факт остается фактом, что я во многих официальных библиотеках C# встречаю использование инлайн методов и goto.
Если в С++ заинлайнить метод можно ключевым словом inline (при этом компилятор может и не заинлайнить, а также нужно вынести реализацию метода в хедер, что типа фу-фу-фу) которое много времени и места не требует, то в C# используются специальные атрибуты для компилятора (что довольно громоздко).

Можете мне рассказывать сколько угодно, что C# для сайтов, что там производительность не важна, но сам Джеффри Рихтер писал о том, что на C# делают десктопные приложения, которые по скорости (с учетом всех опитимизаций) в будущем могут сравняться или опередить программы на С++ за счет того, что .NET оптимизирует код налету (и долго компилируется только первый раз первый вызов какого-то переиспользуэмого кода) под возможности современных процессоров. В то время как компилятор приложения на С++ чтобы не зависеть от артитектуры процессора используют только 100% гарантированные инструкции. Можно наверное сделать проверку и глубоко в библиотеках возможно она делается, но тогда чем С++ отличается от C# если каждое приложение будет тянуть кучу барахла для оптимизации.

Это я к чему? А к тому, что goto используют в майкрософте и не гнушаются. Ничего он не портит. Если можете секономить пару копеек производительности не напрягаясь - почему нет? Может хватит поносить всех и вся, кто использует goto.

Мне кажется, что кто-то когда-то поднял эту тему из "авторитетов" и все теперь повторяют даже не задумывась.

Конечно может среди вас есть те, кто даже затестил и вы задумывались - тогда делитесь своим опытом. Потому что у меня нет фантазии и опыта и реальной задачи на которой можно это проверить. Прогонка в циклах ничего не дает - все это оптимизируется и кэшируется и тому подобное.

Я не создавал эту тему, потому что знал, что у меня нет опыта с вами огрызаться. Но та теория, которую я получил в учебниках, говорит о том, что ничего страшного в goto в C# нету. Рихтер очень сильно обращал внимание на производительность в своей книге по дотнету. И ничего не упомянул про goto. А значит - это не важно. Он также мало что говорил про оптимизацию, потому что с его слов "это дело меняется с каждым выпуском".

Кроме этого с помощью goto можна прыгать по свитчах и делать более оптимизированные решения какой-то вещи, которую никто лет 1000 трогать не будет.

**Итак резюмирую:**

- стандартные конструкции позволяют компилятору лучше понять ваши намерения и оптимизировать код (согласен с клинкодерами). Ведь оптимизация постоянно развивается и меняется, нужны понятные и стабильные конструкции.
- но goto часто позволяет написать код понятнее и без лишних вызовов методов и затрат времени и места на экране, и в простых конструкциях врятли влияет на производительность (где нет магии компилятора) - извините не предоставил.
- Как заметил товарищ  @avp - метки и goto используются для построения конечных автоматов FSM (кстати подтверждаю - часто приводятся примеры скомпилированного кода итераторов с метками и goto)
- хватит чмырить людей за goto, нужно конструктивно подходить к вопросу. Майкрософт бы его выпилил с языка, который создавался совсем недавно и цель которого было вобрать в себя все плюсы всех решений

Анализируя использование goto в библиотеках майкрософт я пришел к выводу, что они используются в таких случаях:

- не захламлять список методов класса какими-то локальными 1 раз используемыми методами
- невозможно постоянно абстрагироваться и строить код на абстракциях, иногда нужно сделать алгоритм из простых действий на множество строк, операции которых нет смысла заключать в отдельные методы, так как их непонятно как назвать и их много и они будут захламлять класс **(метод можно создать внутри метода - так что это типа не считается, но тогда это захламление метода?)** Кстати, если мы через методы попытаемся сделать подобие сквозного исполнения кода - то ничего не получится из этого читабельного и без дублирования (придется создавать какие-то запутанные рекурсии чтоли).

Есть еще такое мнение, что если разрешить разочек - завтра все везде будут пихать goto где нужно и где не нужно. Именно поэтому нужно нужно понимать и объяснять людям в команде почему выбрано такое решение, а не потому что "низзя"

**Вот представлю парочку причин для запрета goto:**

1. мне он не нравится, потому что он плохо изучен, все его хэйтят и наверное небезосновательно и времени тратить на изучение ньюансов я не хочу. Давайте писать такими конструкциями, которые еще 100 лет будут работать стабильно. (без goto, инкрементов с присваиваниями, и замыканий в циклах)
2. разница в производительности не доказана goto/методы
   поэтому я считаю, что goto нет смысла использовать, потому что он не нужен, а не потому что он плох.

**Вот представлю парочку причин для согласия с goto:**

1. мне он нравится, потому что разница в производительности не доказана goto/методы
   поэтому я считаю, что методы без повода нет смысла использовать, потому они захламляют класс ненужными одномоментными методами **(метод можно создать внутри метода - так что это типа не считается, но тогда это захламление метода?)**
2. goto позволяет создать сквозной case код и прыгать по нему - тем самым оптимизируя код на максимум и при этом он будет читабельнее, чем использование методов с дженерик названиями, которые будут рекурсивно вызывать друг друга. Goto можно использовать в паре с switch.

---

Где я видел goto:
https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs,391
https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Buffer.cs
https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Convert.Base64.cs
https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/DateTime.cs,807
https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Decimal.DecCalc.cs,620

Очень хотел найти пример, который видел около полугода назад в решарпере, но найти не могу. Там был простецкий метод как мой. И вместо выделения повторяющегося кода в метод - был использован GOTO.

Кстати в оправдание использования goto вместо создания методов - это избегания захламления класса, вот что я имею в виду:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Когда пытаешься найти нужный метод, через выпадающий список, как показано, или через . внутри класса - выпадает кучу хлама, и как назло чтобы выбрать нужный - нужно набирать больше буковок для автоподстановки.**(метод можно создать внутри метода - так что это типа не считается, но тогда это захламление метода?)**

https://ru.pdfdrive.com/clr-via-c-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5-microsoftnet-framework-45-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5-c-d170309805.html стр 798

По поводу inline - если бы компилятор был такой умный зачем это:

стр 284 - про оптимизацию вызовов методов, однако:

стр 808 - ставит [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)] на пустышку метод

стр 842 - я наверное не понял о чем речь, но слова такие[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Советую почитать книгу "Совершенный код" С.Макконнелл. Там есть тема про goto в главе 17. Вот резюме автора: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На тему "вызов метода - большие затраты" и прочих схожих высказываний - подобного рода микрооптимизации не пригождаются в подавляющем большинстве современных проектов ибо практически никогда не будут бутылочным горлышком. Читабельность и удобство поддержки кода практически всегда перевешивает преждевременную закладку микрооптимизаций

Comment: Опять мы возвращаемся к читабельности. Отлично, но правильное использование goto делает код таким же читабельным. А неправильное использование вызовов методов и if может породить такой же нечитабельный код. Так что я вижу только предвзятое отношение и не более.

Comment: Я это не по отношению к конкретно goto, а в целом про оправдание сомнительных изменений кода ради преждевременных микрооптимизаций. Как по мне в создании "лишних" методов, структур и прочего "барахла" - не только нет ничего криминального, но это и чаще всего на пользу проекту

Comment: Ну Вы и филосов:)

Comment: Компилятор заинлайнит методы там, где нужно. Пытаетесь привести как повод для нагромождения в кучу кода то, чего нет. Итого, просто разбивка кода на методы ради читабельности никак не затормозит приложение, так как в скомпилированной сборке однократно используемые методы заинлайнятся и будет один большой метод выполняться. Итого: `goto` - "фэ" только тупо потому что он не нужен, а не потому что он `goto`. А для конечных автоматов есть `switch-case`. Кстати, вопрос производительности с `goto` не связан вообще никак, совсем, никаким боком. Ну либо приведите пример, давайте бенчмарки погоняем.

Comment: Если не касаться производительности - читайте 2й коммент выше.

Answer (score -2):

goto плохой не потому что он goto, а потому что он ПОЗВОЛЯЕТ использовать себя неправильно, а так же ПОЗВОЛЯЕТ код сделать нечитабельным.

> Все что может быть сделано неправильно рано или поздно будет сделано неправильно с вероятностью в 100% - один из законов Мерфи

В примере был код размером в 8 строк. Если же это метод размером с 30-50 строк - ты станешь запутываться. А если там будет несколько goto -- тем более.

Самое плохое что делает goto - это то что код перестает быть линейным и с любой точки можно перейти в любую точку. Даже если это делать в рамках одного метода. А это значит потеря контроля и потеря понимания как работает код. Если в коде используется goto - ты никогда не можешь быть уверенным на 100% что его использовали правильно.

Более того, Artem, тебе код кажется читабельным ровно до того момента пока ты его написал. Если пройдет 2-4-6 месяцев ты заглядываешь в код и перестаешь понимать куда ведет goto и почему. Твой код понятен тебе ровно пока он свеж в твоей памяти поэтому ты с таким усердием рассказываешь о полезности goto. На практике же любая нелинейность кода приводит к тому что тебе приходится ДУМАТЬ как код себя поведет и не сделает ли он чего-то лишнего.

В 99,99% случаев код должен быть ПРОЩЕ для чтения и понимания, но совсем не быстрее исполнятся.

Тем более, что более высокая скорость работы goto недоказана.

Ты говоришь что правильное понимание как использовать goto не делает код менее читабельным. А я говорю что делает. Почему? Да потому что код перестает быть линейным. Вот и все. Нелинейный код НЕ МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ ЧИТАБЕЛЬНЫМ В ПРИНЦИПЕ. Потому что он НЕЛИНЕЙНЫЙ. А в нелинейном коде ты не можешь быть уверенным как он себя поведет без дополнительных усилий мозга.

Майкрсофт используют? И что с того? В майкрсофт сидит очень много олдовых программистов которые так привыкли потому что писали на более низкоуровневых языках) Чем такое оправдание их действий лучше твоего обьяснения об "скорости" исполнения?)

Ты можешь привести хотя бы один реальный пример когда "узкое горлышко" приходилось на кокнретное место кода и использование goto это розруливало и вытягивало производительность? Я вот например не могу, а занимаюсь программированием думаю что больше твоего.

но даже если представить что это так и есть - то это все равно будет ситуацией-исключением. А во всех остальных случаях лучше не использовать все что относится к unsafe code потому что unsafe code на то и unsafe code потому, что позволяет программисту стрелять себе в ногу.

**А если он позволяет это - то это будут делать.**

А если ты работаешь не сам, то можно выстрелить не только себе в ногу, но и всей команде.

### Вывод:

> Нелинейность кода - более чем хорошая и достаточная причина что бы отказаться от использования goto учитывая что есть способы писать более безопасный и более линейный код

Comment: Любую вещь можно довести до абсурда. В C# есть много чего, что очень запутывает, если не знать нюансов. Вообще без знаний можно много где накуралесить. Поэтому я думаю, что это правило для тех джунов, которые посмотрели пару роликов про C#. Уже писал и писал - что используя методы - можно написать нечитабельно. Поеэтому это  отговорка.

Comment: _с любой точки можно перейти в любую точку_ - в C# это не так, там достаточно много ограничений куда можно переходить

Comment: _Нелинейный код НЕ МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ ЧИТАБЕЛЬНЫМ В ПРИНЦИПЕ_ - таким образом, стоит запретить и все операторы цикла и ветвления :)

Comment: @Grundy запрещать не нужно. Но если есть возможность - не использовать. Не использовать goto более чем возможно. Обойтись без циклов и ветвлений - нет. Но кстате в шарпе такой штуки нет, а вот в свифте иф много где можно заменить guard-ом что повышает линейность кода и облегчает его читабельность. Нужно стремится к линейности.

Comment: _Обойтись без циклов и ветвлений_ конечно можно, достаточно использовать goto :-D

Comment: @Grundy смешно) Но пожалуй нет, спасибо)))